# Unhide /etc dir but NOT using 'AppleShowAllFiles'. Possible?

Tags: finder, macos

I frequently use and edit config files inside /etc on OS X Lion.
I would like to be able to access this dir in Finder easily, but don't want to unhide hidden files system-wide using `defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles`.

Anyone know how?

Comment: What files do you edit here as Apple has tended to move config elsewhere so only old Unix files are there - if you do this often aren't you using the terminal a lot.

Comment: Hi Mark. It's usually to edit apache config files when setting up vhosts, ssl certs etc. It's a lot of cut and paste work which I find far easier to do in GUI text editors than terminal. Often I want to 'save to' something in /etc/apache2 from within an application too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable ShowAllFiles one more time, long enough to drag `/etc` onto your Finder sidebar.  From then on, `/etc` will be available in Finder and in Open and Save As dialogs, regardless of ShowAllFiles.

Answer (score 5):

On my system running Lion (10.7.4), the command `sudo chflags -h nohidden /etc` revealed the `/etc` folder at the top level of my hard drive.

The `-h` flag to `chflags` makes it act on a symbolic link rather than on the linked file.

The `man` page for `chflags` states "Unless the -H or -L options are given, chflags on a symbolic link always succeeds and has no effect." The behavior I observe when I run it is not consistent with this description: I very much do see an effect when I run `chflags` on this particular symlink.

If that solution doesn't work for you, or if you don't want to make /etc visible to all users on your system but you *do* want to easily navigate there in the Finder and in Open, Save, etc. dialog boxes, you could run a command like `ln -s /etc ~/etc`. That would create a (visible) symbolic link to the `/etc` directory in your home directory. When you double click it, it would open the `/etc` directory (actually the `/Private/etc` directory because `/etc` is a symlink thereto in OS X).

Comment: That symlink to /etc idea is excellent! Such a good idea I didn't need to try your first solution. thanks!

Comment: I can confirm that the `sudo chflags -h nohidden /etc` command still works in Yosemite - thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to be able to access this dir in Finder easily …
>
> from within apps …

In Finder or any *Open file…* window, you can type:

- <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd><kbd>⌘ command</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and type any directory you want to go to in that window, e.g. `/etc`, with auto-completion.
- <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd><kbd>⌘ command</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> <sup>1</sup>  to toggle hide/unhide of any dotfiles or other hidden files, e.g. `.zshrc`, `/etc`. Then when you're done toggle it back—for *Open file…* dialogues it will reset after the window is closed.     <sup>1</sup> <sub>Works with macOS Sierra and later.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Although its not exactly what you want, you could make an *Application* with **Automator**.

To do so:

- Open **Automator**.
- Select **Work Flow**.
- Select **Run Shell Script** and type `open /etc`.
- Hit *Save* and choose **Application** as the format.

You will, then, be able to open the **etc** folder by double clicking the *Application* you've just created.

Comment: Thanks, that's an idea, but I often want to be able to save to or open from /etc/* from within apps (Apache configs and SSL certs etc)