# How to display tagged files inside hidden directories?

Tags: finder, macos, finder-tag

Keeping hidden files **hidden**, how can I see content inside hidden directories using Finder [tags](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202754).

I can assign a *tag* to directory `A`, but it *does not* show in Finder when I list all *tag*-tagged content.

```
.hidden_directory/
├── A
│   ├── a
│   │   └── 1.0
│   │       ├── bin
│   │       │   └── abc
...
```

Is this possible?

EDIT: I was able to successfully retrieve any content inside directories like `Documents`, even if those directories have been deliberately hidden via `chflags hidden <FILENAME>`.

This is not too bad, but it would be useful if I could add tags to some of the contents inside `.directories` to quickly access them via the GUI, but without turning hidden files on.

EDIT2: [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27443/showing-hidden-files-in-specific-directories?rq=1) could help some people, but it's not quite exactly what I want to accomplish.

EDIT3: The [first answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54371/unhide-etc-dir-but-not-using-appleshowallfiles-possible?rq=1) also helps, but I was hoping I could use *tags* instead of dragging a directory to the sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what I was looking for, but here is a neat trick that satisfies most of my needs.

Create a new *directory*, hide it via `chflags hidden directory`, deposit tagged content in it.

Finder will cooperate with us and display all tagged content.

[image: file is inside a hidden directory]

`file` is tagged `dev` and exists in a directory hidden via `chflags`. I named the directory `dev` as well for convenience, but this is not strictly necessary.